# How can I complexify $\cos(t)+\sin(2t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I'm working out a practice problem on complexification in the usual format where it is $Ay''+By'+Cy+D$ which is equal to some trigonometric function. However, I'm stumped on how to approach this problem where this expression is equal to $\cos(t)+\sin(2t)$.

My initial though was to do $\cos(t)=\Re[\cos(t)+i\sin(t)]=\Re e^{it}$. However, I would be left with $\sin(2t)=\Im e^{2it}$, which give me different bases where I won't be able to use the Method of Undetermined Coefficients to find a general solution. Could anyone provide some insight on how to solve this problem? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: use$$\cos x\pm i\sin x=e^{\pm ix}\implies\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}),\,\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$to express $\cos t+\sin 2t$ as a linear combination of $e^{\pm it},\,e^{\pm2it}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexification:

$$
Ay''+By'+Cy+D = \cos t+\sin (2t)+i(\sin t+\cos(2t))=e^{it}+ie^{-i2t}
$$

Now as the ode is linear

$$
\cases{
Ay_1''+By_1'+Cy_1+D = e^{it}\\
Ay_2''+By_2'+Cy_2+D = ie^{-i2t}\\
y = y_1+y_2
}
$$